# Kruskal’s Minimum Spanning Tree programm(C) getting segmentation fault (core dumped) error when i try to run it on machine other than my own

Tags: c, minimum-spanning-tree

I have an issue with program to find minimum-spanning-tree it works properly without any issues on my own machine but when I tried to run it on another computers  i got segmentation fault (core dumped) error.I cant no find reason why it happens.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// struktura wierzcholka

struct Edge

{

    int src;
    int dest;
    int weight;

};

// struktura wazonego grafu nieskierowanego

struct Graph
{

    int V; //liczba wierzcholkow
    int E; //liczba krawedzi

    struct Edge* edge; //tablica wierzcholkow

};

struct Graph* createGraph(int V, int E)

{

    struct Graph* graph = (struct Graph*) malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));

    graph->V = V;
    graph->E = E;

    graph->edge = (struct Edge*) malloc(graph->E * sizeof(struct Edge));

    return graph;

}

struct subset //struktura podzbioru wierzcholka

{

    int p; //parent
    int rank;

};

int FindSet(struct subset array[], int i) //znajdz zbioru elemntu i korzystajac z kompresji sciezek
{

    //  znajdz korzen i uczyn go ojcem i  

    if (array[i].p != i)
    {

        array[i].p = FindSet(array, array[i].p);

    }

    return array[i].p;

}

void Union(struct subset arrayofsubsets[], int x, int y)

{

    int x1 = FindSet(arrayofsubsets, x);
    int y1 = FindSet(arrayofsubsets, y);

    //przylacz drzewo mniejszej randze do pod korzen drzewa o wyzszej randze

    if (arrayofsubsets[x1].rank < arrayofsubsets[y1].rank)
    {

        arrayofsubsets[x1].p = y1;

    }
    else if (arrayofsubsets[x1].rank > arrayofsubsets[y1].rank)
    {

        arrayofsubsets[y1].p = x1;
    }

    //jesli rangi takie same jedno staje się korzeniem i zwieksza //range  

    else
    {

        arrayofsubsets[y1].p = x1;
        arrayofsubsets[x1].rank++;

    }

}

int Compare(const void* a, const void* b)

{
    struct Edge* Edge1 = (struct Edge*) a;
    struct Edge* Edge2 = (struct Edge*) b;
    return Edge1->weight > Edge2->weight;
}

struct Graph* AddEdge(struct Graph* graph, int index, int src, int dest, int weight)
{

    graph->edge[index].src = src;
    graph->edge[index].dest = dest;
    graph->edge[index].weight = weight;

    return graph;
}

void Kruskal(struct Graph* graph)

{

    int V = graph->V;

    struct Edge MST[V];  // minimalne dzewo rozpinajace

    int e, i, v;

    qsort(graph->edge, graph->E, sizeof(graph->edge[0]), Compare);

    struct subset *arrayofsubsets = (struct subset*) malloc(V * sizeof(struct subset));

    //  stworz podzbiory jednoelementowe (podzbior wskazuje sam siebie )

    for (v = 0; v < V; ++v)
    {

        arrayofsubsets[v].p = v;
        arrayofsubsets[v].rank = 0;

    }
e=0;
    while (e < (V - 1))
    {

        //wybierz najmniejszy wierzcholek

        struct Edge nextedge = graph->edge[i++];

        int ru = FindSet(arrayofsubsets, nextedge.src);

        int rv = FindSet(arrayofsubsets, nextedge.dest);

        if (ru != rv)
        {

            MST[e++] = nextedge;
            Union(arrayofsubsets, ru, rv);

        }
    }



    printf("MST edges\n");

    for (i = 0; i < e; ++i)
    {

        printf("V1 %d V2 %d weight %d\n", MST[i].src, MST[i].dest, MST[i].weight);
    }

    return;

}

int main()

{

    int V = 6;
    int E = 9;

    struct Graph* graph = createGraph(V, E);

    //boki kwadratu
    graph = AddEdge(graph, 0, 0, 1, 5);
    graph = AddEdge(graph, 1, 0, 2, 3);
    graph = AddEdge(graph, 2, 1, 3, 2);
    graph = AddEdge(graph, 3, 2, 3, 8);

    //przekątne kwadratu
    graph = AddEdge(graph, 4, 0, 3, 4);
    graph = AddEdge(graph, 5, 1, 2, 20);

    //boki kwadratu przyleglego do pierwszego kwadratu  
    //graph=AddEdge(graph,2,1,3,2);
    graph = AddEdge(graph, 6, 1, 4, 1);
    graph = AddEdge(graph, 7, 4, 5, 0);
    graph = AddEdge(graph, 8, 5, 3, 21);

    Kruskal(graph);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It might not explain your segfault, but your `Compare()` function is not correct for use with `qsort()`.  When `a` is less than `b` it should return -1, but it returns 0 in that case instead.

Comment: Since you're content in `Kruskal()` to declare variable `MST` as a variable-length array, it's unclear why you decline to do the same with `arrayofsubsets`.  That inconsistency is not inherently erroneous, though.

Comment: `Union` looks like the C keyword `union`.  It is poor programming practice to make the name of a function the same as a C operator, with the only difference being capitalization.  The compiler will not have any problems, but us humans will be confused

Comment: this line: `return Edge1->weight > Edge2->weight;` should be written as: `return Edge1->weight - Edge2->weight;`

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc): 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting the returned value just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest removing the 'casting'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program crash at line 188:

```
printf("V1 %d V2 %d weight %d\n", MST[i].src, MST[i].dest,MST[i].weight);
```

and at this line

```
int e,i,v,ru,rv;
```

you didn't inizialize vars e and i. To fix:

```
int e=0,i=0, [..]
```

and the program will work

Comment: i initialized them and it worked like a charm but i am still curious why it works properly on some machines

Comment: because in some machine that two vars are allocated in a region with no random values, but only zeroes. So it is initialized for you

Comment: _in a region with no random values,_ There aren't magic regions. It simply is UB.

Answer (score 2):

Compiler is giving you two severe warnings

```
test.c:129:9: warning: ‘i’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
  int e, i, v, ru, rv;
         ^
test.c:159:9: warning: ‘e’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
    MST[e++] = nextedge;
```

In function Kruskal you have

```
while (e < (V - 1))
{
    //wybierz najmniejszy wierzcholek

    struct Edge nextedge = graph->edge[i++]; <<------
```

where i is used un-initialized. variable with local scope/automatic storage duration is not initialized, so i can have any value.

Init all local variable

```
int e = 0;
int i = 0;
[...]
```

or just before the their first use, like

```
i = 0;
e = 0;
while (e < (V - 1))
{
    //wybierz najmniejszy wierzcholek

    struct Edge nextedge = graph->edge[i++];
```